# What is causing LaTeX error: Undefined control sequence

Tags: errors

I'm trying to show this Matlab text, but apparently there is an error in the line

```
title('z(x)=1+e^(-2x)*cos(\omegax)');
```

I thought anything I put between `$`..`$` LaTeX would read as an mathematical expression. And since the line has only mathematical expressions, I cant find the error.

Can any of you help me?

This is the whole block:

```
x=linspace(0,2,1000);
w1=0.1;
w2=0.5;
w3=1.0;
z1=1+exp(-2*x).*cos(w1*x);
z2=1+exp(-2*x).*cos(w2*x);
z3=1+exp(-2*x).*cos(w3*x);
figure(1)
plot(x,z1,'k-',x,z2,'k--',x,z3,'k.');
grid on;
xlabel('tempo(s)');
zlabel('z(x)');
title('z(x)=1+e^(-2x)*cos(\omegax)');
legend('\omega=0,1','\omega=0,5','\omega=1');
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the line in the .log file?

Comment: i see `\omegax` on the next to last line.  should probably be `omega x' with a space.

Answer (score 2):

`\omegax` is undefined. You probably want `\cos(\omega x)` in your line `title('z(x)=1+e^(-2x)*cos(\omegax)');`.